# By click the Nextbutton Textview from the firstactivity is displayed in second activity

Tags: android

```
Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v1)
            {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecActivity.class);
                   intent.putExtra("fname",Text.getText().toString());
                   startActivity(intent);
            }
});
```

Comment: what is your question ? what is your problem ?

Comment: App crash occur when i put this code...

Comment: I need Proper method to get textview on next activity...but the text is same

Comment: 07-10 13:01:10.058: W/System.err(1361):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/index.html

Comment: `First:` Change your question to getting crash or something. `Second:` Post log and `SecActivity` code where you are fetching intent data.

Answer (score 0):

to get the data from intent on second activity use this method

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
```

and set the text in a TextView

```
textView.setText(intent.getStringExtra("fname"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this in SecActivity.java file

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 

if(intent.getStringExtra("fname")!=null){

textView.setText(intent.getStringExtra("fname"));
else{
//put your text if value not present in fname
}
```